# Google java format in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-formatting, intellij-plugin, google-java-format

I am using the Google-java-formatter in IntelliJ IDEA.
I tried all the option present under setting > editor > code Style > java but not able to change this behavior.

```
private void insertOfflinePreferences(String loginId, String clientId, List<AlertPrefsNgBO> alertPrefsNgBOS) {

List<SubscriptionAlertEntity> subscriptionAlertEntities = subscriptionAlertRepository.getSubscriptionAlertEntities(login);
```

This line is getting formatted as

```
private void insertOfflinePreferences(
  String loginId, String clientId, List<AlertPrefsNgBO> alertPrefsNgBOS) {


List<SubscriptionAlertEntity> subscriptionAlertEntities =
          subscriptionAlertRepository.getSubscriptionAlertEntities(login);
```

**I don't want the line change. It is doing same for the stream operations in java.**

Answer (score 4):

[Quoting the github page](https://github.com/google/google-java-format):

> Note: There is no configurability as to the formatter's algorithm for formatting. This is a deliberate design decision to unify our code formatting on a single format.

Either use google-java-formatter, or don't. (I simply stopped caring about GJF's choices *years* ago, because I'm used to it; and even in cases where it doesn't format it exactly how I'd like, the formatting is not totally disagreeable).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you want the IntelliJ to stop wrapping your lines ?

For that you can set the Hard Wrap field to a higher value. The default is 120, which means that every line of more than 120 characters will be wrapped.

You can find this parameter in Settings>Editor>Code Style (And not in Settings>Editor>Code Style>Java)

Comment: This has not affect. I changed it to 500.

Comment: Google Java Format has a limit of 100 ([link to test](https://github.com/google/google-java-format/blob/5f46e2e/core/src/test/java/com/google/googlejavaformat/java/StringWrapperTest.java#L52)), and doesn't look at what IntelliJ or any other IDE has configured.